# Prove that every vertex has degree of 2

Tags: graph-theory

I have to prove that in a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $n$ edges which has no isolated or pendant vertices, every vertex has degree 2.

Now I know that $$\sum_{v\in V} d(v)=2|E|=2n$$

but I suppose I also have to prove every vertex has same degree and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What is a "pendant" vertex?

Comment: @JMoravitz Presumably of degree 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** From the equation you gave, we can divide both sides by $n$ to get the average degree:

$$\frac1n \sum_{v\in V} d(v)=2$$

Now, if any vertex has a degree greater than the average, there must necessarily be another vertex with a degree lower than the average. What does that imply?

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: The logic should go the other way (if pendant *then* there exists a vertex with degree greater than 2), but the core idea is excellent.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you! I think the logic is solid, though: we know from the outset that there are no isolated or pendant vertices, so the only other possibility is if there is a vertex of degree greater than 2, which leads to a contradiction.